# Do very long methods always need refactoring?

Tags: c++, refactoring

I face a situation where we have many very long methods, 1000 lines or more.

To give you some more detail, we have a list of incoming high level commands, and each <s>generates</s> results in a longer (sometime huge) list of lower level commands. There's a factory creating an instance of a class for each incoming command. Each class has a process method, where all the lower level commands are <s>generated</s> added in sequence. As I said, these sequences of commands and their parameters cause quite often the process methods to reach thousands of lines.

There are a lot of repetitions. Many command patterns are shared between different commands, but the code is repeated over and over. That leads me to think refactoring would be a very good idea.

On the contrary, the specs we have come exactly in the same form as the current code. Very long list of commands for each incoming one. When I've tried some refactoring, I've started to feel uncomfortable with the specs. I miss the obvious analogy between the specs and code, and lose time digging into newly created common classes.

Then here the question: in general, do you think such very long methods would always need refactoring, or in a similar case it would be acceptable?
(unfortunately refactoring the specs is not an option)

---

edit: 
I have removed every reference to "generate" cause it was actually confusing. It's not auto generated code.

```
class InCmd001 {

  OutMsg process ( InMsg& inMsg ) {

     OutMsg outMsg = OutMsg::Create();

     OutCmd001 outCmd001 = OutCmd001::Create();
     outCmd001.SetA( param.getA() );
     outCmd001.SetB( inMsg.getB() );

     outMsg.addCmd( outCmd001 );

     OutCmd016 outCmd016 = OutCmd016::Create();
     outCmd016.SetF( param.getF() );

     outMsg.addCmd( outCmd016 );

     OutCmd007 outCmd007 = OutCmd007::Create();
     outCmd007.SetR( inMsg.getR() );

     outMsg.addCmd( outCmd007 );

     // ......

     return outMsg;
  }
}
```

here the example of one incoming command class (manually written in pseudo c++)

Comment: Can you give us some which pseudo code which shows us the pattern of these huge methods?

Comment: Looks like it could be a candidate for code generation.

Comment: @Binary Worrier - The sample is a very simplified version, just to give you an idea. Anyway, I agree that even the real code could be somehow autogenerated, but this is not going to happen any time soon.

Comment: Be wary of words like "always" and "never". All sweeping generalisations are wrong.

Comment: @Mike what about the word "all"? Is that a sweeping generalization too? :p

Comment: Thank you everybody for the very smart answers and comments. Many of them have triggered a lot of interesting ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand exactly where you're coming from, and can see exactly why you've structured your code the way it is, but it needs to change.

The uncertainty you feel when you attempt to refactor can be ameliorated by writing unit tests. If you've tests specific to each spec, then the code for each spec can be refactored until you're blue in the face, and you can have confidence in it.

A second option, is it possible to automatically generate your code from a data structure?
If you've a core suite of classes that do the donkey work and edge cases, you can auto-generate the repetitive 1000 line methods as often as you wish.

However, there are exceptions to every rule.
If the methods are a literal interpretation of the spec (very little additional logic), and the specs change infrequently, and the "common" portions (i.e. bits that happen to be the same right now) of the specs change at different times, and you're not going to be asked to get a 10x performance gain out of the code anytime soon, then (and only then) . . . you may be better off with what you have.

. . . but on the whole, refactor.

Comment: +1 for generating the code from a data structure - I consider that a "very problem specific language" (VPSL?) just to bring the verbosity to managable levels.

Answer (score 40):

Code never *needs* refactoring. The code either works, or it doesn't. And if it works, the code doesn't *need* anything.

The need for refactoring comes from *you*, the programmer. The person reading, writing, maintaining and extending the code.

If you have trouble understanding the code, it needs to be refactored. If you would be more productive by cleaning up and refactoring the code, it needs to be refactored.

In general, I'd say it's a good idea *for your own sake* to refactor 1000+ line functions. But you're not doing it because the code needs it. You're doing it because that makes it easier for you to understand the code, test its correctness, and add new functionality.

On the other hand, if the code is automatically generated by another tool, you'll never need to read it or edit it. So what'd be the point in refactoring it?

Comment: well, for your own sake and for the sake of any other humans that have to read the code, which is often many many people. But the essence of what you are saying is true.

Comment: On a large project, you are never the only one maintaining that code. If your method is too long, chances are, others will struggle when the time comes to updating it (even you as well, 1 year later, when you forgot what it did)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, always. 1000 lines is at least 10x longer than any function should ever be, and I'm tempted to say 100x, except that when dealing with input parsing and validation  it can become natural to write functions with 20 or so lines.

**Edit:** Just re-read your question and I'm not clear on one point - are you talking about machine generated code that no-one has to touch? In which case I would leave things as they are.

Answer (score 10):

Refectoring is not the same as writing from scratch. While you should never write code like this, before you refactor it, you need to consider the costs of refactoring in terms of time spent, the associated risks in terms of breaking code that already works, and the net benefits in terms of future time saved.  Refactor only if the net benefits outweigh the associated costs and risks.

Sometimes wrapping and rewriting can be a safer and more cost effective solution, even if it appears expensive at first glance.

Comment: I like that this is NOT the end-all answer. Only the Opener knows all factors associated with refactoring this code.

Answer (score 6):

Long methods need refactoring if they are maintained (and thus need to be understood) by humans.

Comment: Sound unlikely that he talks about generated code. If so, then I'd vote for close because of 'stealing our time'

Comment: so machine code doesn't need refactoring? what if you want to overcome some memory constraint? Readability is one of the most important thing in programming, but there are many things more

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, code for humans first. I don't agree with the common idea that functions need to be short. I think what you need to aim at is when a human reads your code they grok it quickly.

To this effect it's a good idea to simplify things as much as possible--but not more than that. It's a good idea to delegate roughly one task for each function. There is no rule as for what "roughly one task" means: you'll have to use your own judgement for that. But do recognize that a function split into too many other functions itself reduces readability. Think about the human being who reads your function for the first time: they would have to follow one function call after another, constantly context-switching and maintaining a stack in their mind. This is a task for machines, not for humans.

Find the balance.

Here, you see how important naming things is. You will see it is not that easy to choose names for variables and functions, it takes time, but on the other hand it can save a lot of confusion on the human reader's side. Again, find the balance between saving your time and the time of the friendly humans who will follow you.

As for repetition, it's a bad idea. It's something that needs to be fixed, just like a memory leak. It's a ticking bomb.

As others have said before me, changing code can be expensive. You need to do the thinking as for whether it will pay off to spend all this time and effort, facing the risks of change, for a better code. You will possibly lose lots of time and make yourself one headache after another now, in order to possibly save lots of time and headache later.

Comment: My words. Just to add this: don't change running code without a real good reason.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the related question [How many lines of code is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981/how-many-lines-of-code-is-too-many).  There are quite a few tidbits of wisdom throughout the answers there.

To repost a quote (although I'll attempt to comment on it a little more here)... A while back, I read this [passage from Ovid's journal](https://use-perl.github.io/user/Ovid/journal/38616/):

> I recently wrote some code for
> Class::Sniff which would detect "long
> methods" and report them as a code
> smell. I even wrote a blog post about
> how I did this (quelle surprise, eh?).
> That's when Ben Tilly asked an
> embarrassingly obvious question: how
> do I know that long methods are a code
> smell?
>
> I threw out the usual justifications,
> but he wouldn't let up. He wanted
> information and he cited the excellent
> book Code Complete as a
> counter-argument. I got down my copy
> of this book and started reading "How
> Long Should A Routine Be" (page 175,
> second edition). The author, Steve
> McConnell, argues that routines should
> not be longer than 200 lines. Holy
> crud! That's waaaaaay to long. If a
> routine is longer than about 20 or 30
> lines, I reckon it's time to break it
> up.
>
> Regrettably, McConnell has the cheek
> to cite six separate studies, all of
> which found that longer routines were
> not only not correlated with a greater
> defect rate, but were also often
> cheaper to develop and easier to
> comprehend. As a result, the latest
> version of Class::Sniff on github now
> documents that longer routines may not
> be a code smell after all. Ben was
> right. I was wrong.

(The rest of the post, on TDD, is worth reading as well.)

Coming from the "shorter methods are better" camp, this gave me a lot to think about.

Previously my large methods were generally limited to "I need inlining here, and the compiler is being uncooperative", or "for one reason or another the giant switch block really does run faster than the dispatch table", or "this stuff is only called exactly in sequence and I really really don't want function call overhead here".  All relatively rare cases.

In your situation, though, I'd have a large bias toward not touching things: refactoring carries some inherent risk, and it may currently outweigh the reward.  (Disclaimer: I'm slightly paranoid; I'm usually the guy who ends up fixing the crashes.)

Consider spending your efforts on tests, asserts, or documentation that can strengthen the existing code and tilt the risk/reward scale before any attempt to refactor: [invariant checks](http://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/writing-correct-code-part-1-invariants-binary-search-part-4a/), [bound function](http://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/writing-correct-code-part-2-bound-functions-binary-search-part-4b/) analysis, and [pre/postcondition tests](http://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/writing-correct-code-part-3-preconditions-and-postconditions-binary-search-part-4c/); any other useful concepts from [DBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract); maybe even a parallel implementation in another language (maybe something message oriented like Erlang would give you a better perspective, given your code sample) or even some sort of [formal logical representation](http://hol.sourceforge.net/) of the spec you're trying to follow if you have some time to burn.

Any of these kinds of efforts generally have a few results, even if you don't get to refactor the code: you learn something, you increase your (and your organization's) understanding of and ability to use the code and specifications, you might find a few holes that really do need to be filled *now*, and you become more confident in your ability to make a change with less chance of disastrous consequences.

As you gain a better understanding of the problem domain, you may find that there are different ways to refactor you hadn't thought of previously.

This isn't to say "thou shalt have a full-coverage test suite, and DBC asserts, and a formal logical spec".  It's just that you are in a typically imperfect situation, and diversifying a bit -- looking for novel ways to approach the problems you find (maintainability? fuzzy spec? ease of learning the system?) -- may give you a small bit of forward progress and some increased confidence, after which you can take larger steps.

So think less from the "too many lines is a problem" perspective and more from the "this might be a code smell, what problems is it going to cause for us, and is there anything easy and/or rewarding we can do about it?"

Leaving it cooking on the backburner for a bit -- coming back and revisiting it as time and coincidence allows (e.g. "I'm working near the code today, maybe I'll wander over and see if I can't document the assumptions a bit better...") may produce good results.  Then again, getting royally ticked off and deciding something *must* be done about the situation is also effective.

Have I managed to be wishy-washy enough here?  My point, I think, is that the code smells, the patterns/antipatterns, the best practices, etc -- they're there to serve you.  Experiment to get used to them, and then take what makes sense for your current situation, and leave the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I think you first need to "refactor" the specs. If there are repetitions in the spec it also will become easier to read, if it makes use of some "basic building blocks".

---

Edit: As long as you cannot refactor the specs, I wouldn't change the code.
Coding style guides are all made for easier code maintenance, but in your special case the ease of maintenance is achieved by following the spec.

Some people here asked if the code is generated. In my opinion it does not matter: If the code follows the spec "line by line" it makes no difference if the code is generated or hand-written.

Answer (score 2):

1000 thousand lines of code is nothing. We have functions that are 6 to 12 thousand lines long. Of course those functions are so big, that literally things get lost in there, and no tool can help us even look at high level abstractions of them. the code is now unfortunately incomprehensible.
My opinion of functions that are that big, is that they were not written by brilliant programmers but by incompetent hacks who shouldn't be left anywhere near a computer - but should be fired and left flipping burgers at McDonald's. Such code wreaks havok by leaving behind features that cannot be added to or improved upon. (too bad for the customer). The code is so brittle that it cannot be modified by anyone - even the original authors.

And yes, those methods should be refactored, or thrown away.

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever have to read or maintain the generated code?

If yes, then I'd think some refactoring might be in order.

If no, then the higher-level language is really the language you're working with -- the C++ is just an intermediate representation on the way to the compiler -- and refactoring might not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that you've implemented a separate language within your application - have you considered going that way?

Comment: was kinda thinking into that direction as well. Maybe you can write a system which makes all those calls based on some input data; then you could directly feed in the specs, in some format. Because what you describe is basically a second layer of logic (specs-to-calls) that's however executed not by a processor but by a poor programmer. I always like it when my code talks about what it does - if you'd have a main method that basically says "and here we take the specs and perform the calls as specified" your code should become much clearer and much smaller.

Comment: Somehow yes, but what do you mean with "going that way"?

Comment: @nicolas78 You're definitely right, but that will not be possible for long time. There a huge code base and currently specs come as word docs :-(

Answer (score 1):

It has been my understanding that it's recommended that any method over 100 lines of code be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

I think some rules may be a little different in his era when code is most commonly viewed in an IDE.  If the code does not contain exploitable repetition, such that there are 1,000 lines which are going to be referenced once each, and which share a significant number of variables in a clear fashion, dividing the code into 100-line routines each of which is called once may not be that much of an improvement over having a *well-formatted* 1,000-line module which includes #region tags or the equivalent to allow outline-style viewing.

My philosophy is that certain layouts of code generally imply certain things.  To my mind, when a piece of code is placed into its own routine, that suggests that the code will be usable in more than one context (exception: callback handlers and the like in languages which don't support anonymous methods).  If code segment #1 leaves an object in an obscure state which is only usable by code segment #2, and code segment #2 is only usable on a data object which is left in the state created by #1, then absent some compelling reason to put the segments in different routines, they should appear in the same routine.  If a program puts objects through a chain of obscure states extending for many hundreds of lines of code, it might be good to rework the *design* of the code to subdivide the operation into smaller pieces which have more "natural" pre- and post- conditions, but absent some compelling reason to do so, I would not favor splitting up the code without changing the design.

Answer (score 1):

For further reading, I highly recommend the long, insightful, entertaining, and sometimes bitter discussion of this topic over on the [Portland Pattern Repository](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LongFunctionsDiscussion).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen cases where it is not the case (for example, creating an Excel spreadsheet in .Net often requires a lot of line of code for the formating of the sheet), but most of the time, the best thing would be to indeed refactor it.

I personally try to make a function small enough so it all appears on my screen (without affecting the readability of course).

Answer (score 0):

1000 lines? Definitely they need to be refactored. Also not that, for example, default maximum number of executable statements is 30 in [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), well-known coding standard checker.

Answer (score 0):

> Then here the question: in general, do
>   you think such very long methods would
>   always need refactoring,

if you ask in general, we will say **Yes** .

> or in a
>   similar case it would be acceptable?
>   (unfortunately refactoring the specs
>   is not an option)

Sometimes are **acceptable**, but is very unusual, I will give you a pair of examples:
There are some 8 bit microcontrollers called Microchip PIC, that have only a fixed 8 level stack, so you can't nest more than 8 calls, then care must be taken to avoid "stack overflow", so in this special case having many small function (nested) is not the best way to go.
Other example is when doing optimization of code (at very low level) so you have to take account the jump and context saving cost. Use it with care.

**EDIT:**

Even in generated code, you could need to refactorize the way its generated, for example for memory saving, energy saving, generate human readable, beauty, who knows, etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you refactor, when you refactor, add some comments to explain what the heck it's doing.

If it had comments, it would be much less likely a candidate for refactoring, because it would already be easier to read and follow for someone starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There has been very good general advise, here a practical recommendation for your sample:

common patterns can be isolated in plain feeder methods:

```
void AddSimpleTransform(OutMsg & msg, InMsg const & inMsg, 
                        int rotateBy, int foldBy, int gonkBy = 0)
{
   // create & add up to three messages
}
```

You might even improve that by making this a member of OutMsg, and using a fluent interface, such that you can write

```
OutMsg msg;
msg.AddSimpleTransform(inMsg, 12, 17)
   .Staple("print")
   .AddArtificialRust(0.02);
```

which can be an additional improvement under circumstances.

Comment: Actually we do something very similar. But I didn't show it in the example to keep things clear. In practice we write something like:
+outCmd001
  .SetA( param.getA() )
  .SetB( inMsg.getB() );